# To match a variable containing metacharacters using regular expressions in perl

Tags: regex, perl, file

```
$match="";

for($i=0;$i<=$#wor;$i++)
{
$match=$match.$letter[$wor[$i]];
}

print $match;

open ABC,"<words.txt";

while(<ABC>)
{

if($_ =~ /^$match$/ )
{
print "$_";
print "\n";
}
}
```

In the following code, I am not able to match the line of the file i.e. $_ with the variable $match (which contains the actual metacharacters which are to be matched )?
And hence no output is produced
What changes are needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `^` and `$` anchors from your regexp which match the beginning and end of a string.

With them, the regexp will only match lines which *only* contain the meta-characters.

You probably also want to wrap `$match` in `[ .. ]` characters, to indicate that it's a range of characters, and not a word.

For example, if you wanted to exclude any line containing `_` or `%` your `$match` would need to contain `[_$]`

**EDIT** if, per the comments, you only want to match if the meta characters are found at either end, use:

```
if (/^${match}/ || /${match}$/) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: But i want to make search at the beginning and at the end only.

Comment: you could do `if (/^${match}/ || /${match}$/) { ... }`

Comment: To upvote and/or accept an answer is much better "thank u" :).

Comment: @Alnitak - I upvoted this answer, but you should do same and accept it as well, body... Just click up arrow above the number left next to answer and then check mark below that number.